# Is an "unchangable" fixed sized JPanel possible at all?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, resize

I just want to have a fixed sized JPanel which locks in its size (The user should NOT be able to change the size).  How am I supposed to do that?

Comment: PS: Please help yourself by providing your source code.

Comment: Deleted request for a "clear and definitive answer". You're asking for free advice man. If you don't understand an answer, please feel free to ask for clarification.

Comment: Related threads - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651206/fixed-width-variable-height-in-jpanel-with-flow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223530/how-can-i-properly-center-a-jpanel-fixed-size-inside-a-jframe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/316454/can-you-set-a-permanent-size-for-a-jpanel-inside-of-a-jframe

Answer (score 5):

`JPanel` is not resizable by the user.

If you are referring to `JFrame`, you can use `setResizable(false);`.  Say `abc` is a frame, `abc.setResizable(false);`

Comment: To my eye, this question implies a resizable frame.

Answer (score 2):

The panel might be placed in a non-resizable area of a layout (e.g. the *non* `CENTER` constraints of a `BorderLayout`).

For more details, we would need some ASCII art of the proposed GUI in two sizes (the first to show the layout, the 2nd to show how extra width & height should be assigned) and an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html) of your best attempt.